# Inverse of `Data.Text.Encoding.decodeLatin1`?

Tags: haskell, utf-8

Is there a function `f :: Text -> Maybe ByteString` such that forall `x`:

```
f (decodeLatin1 x) == Just x
```

Note, `decodeLatin1` has the signature:

```
decodeLatin1 :: ByteString -> Text
```

I'm concerned that `encodeUtf8` is not what I want, as I'm guessing what it does is just dump the UTF-8 string out as a ByteString, not reverse the changes that `decodeLatin1` made on the way in to characters in the upper half of the character set.

I understand that `f` has to return a `Maybe`, because in general there's Unicode characters that aren't in the Latin character set, but I just want this to round trip at least, in that if we start with a `ByteString` we should get back to it.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: consider this a long comment rather than a solution, because I haven't tested.

I think you can do it with `witch` [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witch-1.1.6.0/docs/Witch.html). It is a general purpose type converter library with a fair amount of type safety. There is a type class called [TryFrom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witch-1.1.6.0/docs/Witch.html#g:3) to perform conversion between types that might fail to cast.

Luckily `witch` provides conversions from/to encondings too, having an instance `TryFrom Text (ISO_8859_1 ByteString)`, meaning that you can convert between `Text` and latin1 encoded `ByteString`. So I think (not tested!!) this should work

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Witch (tryInto, ISO_8859_1)
import Data.Tagged (Tagged(unTagged))

f :: Text -> Maybe ByteString
f s = case tryInto @(ISO_8859_1 ByteString) s of
  Left err -> Nothing
  Right bs -> Just (unTagged bs)
```

Notice that `tryInto` returns a `Either TryFromException s`, so if you want to handle errors you can do it with `Either`. Up to you.

Also, `witch` docs points out that this conversion is done via `String` type, so probably there is an out-of-the-box solution without the need of depending on `witch` package. I don't know such a solution, and looking to the source code hasn't helped

### Edit:

Having read `witch` source code aparently this should work

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Char (isLatin1)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

f :: Text -> Maybe ByteString
f t = if allCharsAreLatin then Just (C.pack str) else Nothing
 where str = T.unpack t
       allCharsAreLatin = all isLatin1 str
```

Answer (score 1):

The latin1 encoding is pretty damn simple -- codepoint X maps to byte X, whenever that's in range of a byte. So just unpack and repack immediately.

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

latin1EncodeText :: T.Text -> Maybe BS.ByteString
latin1EncodeText t = BS.pack (T.unpack t) <$ guard (T.all (<'\256') t)
```

It's possible to avoid the intermediate `String`, but you should probably make sure this is your bottleneck before trying for that.